# Any ideas on how to create a file only readable by my program?

Tags: c++

So I noticed when I want to write external data for my program I have to use  and that inserts my data I want into a notepad.  What Im wondering is, say I wanted to write to a file that my users couldn't edit, like a file that would hold scores and such for a game that I dont want players to be able to edit manually.  Would such a thing be possible through c++ standard library alone, or would I need some other library? And I understand some programs may be able to read it, but Im more oriented towards wether people can read it by simply looking at the notepad.

Comment: Generally, you can't! However, the operating system may have ways for that, but it's unlikely. Anyway, using pure C++ it's impossible.

Comment: @BartoszKP: how does he prevent the players from getting the key that's already on their computer?

Comment: @BartoszKP I read a bit into encryption, do you know any good sources to learn it from, or any good libs?

Comment: @Wooble He doesn't, in general.

Comment: As for license management **this can't be easily done** (because they **may disassemble** your source code). If you want to **keep your file readable** then it'll be even harder because you can't encrypt it (but see previous sentence). What you may do is to write a field in your text file calculated from the other data, a kind of **checksum**. If they manually edit the file then it won't match that checksum and you'll give an error. They may still be able to disassemble your code to see how it's calculated but...hey...will they do it? To be safe you have to save scores _elsewhere_ (server?)

Comment: Theoretically this is impossible. Even if you use encryption, your local machine has all the tools necessary to encrypt a high scores file. So a hacker can *always* edit the high scores file, and release a utility that does so.

Comment: @23curtu Have you tried google?

Comment: I don't see anything unclear in this question. The OP wants to prevent the user from tricking the scores.

Comment: you could write an encrypted file, but users would be able to extract the encryption key from your program. If your program can read and write the file then so can users.

What you're trying to do is basically DRM. You won't be more successful at doing it than everyone else.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti So your saying write some sort of algorithim to write to the file, so my program can disassemble it with ease, but make it hard for users to?

Comment: @tenfour Theoretically every security mechanism can be broken, so that's not really an issue. In practice it's always the cost of breaking the security vs the profit. For a simple computer game simple encryption usually is enough.

Comment: @BartoszKP no, if you are using a server to store the high scores then you can reasonably expect this to be "perfectly" secure from your persective in this question. Is there any real harm in letting users edit the high scores file anyway? If you're not submitting them online or something, then maybe it's best to just leave it in plaintext. Sometimes this is part of the charm of offline games :D

Comment: @23scurtu no. Keep your file in plain text. Add a line with a _checksum_ (still plain text). They can read the file (and even checksum itself) but if they edit it then checksum/hash/check digit won't match (you recalculate each time you open the file) and you'll detect such trick. They can't update checksum according to their changes simply because they don't know how it's calculated (unless they disassemble your source code, possible but not likely for a game).

Comment: @tenfour This server must transfer the key back to the client, so it's not very different in terms of discussion about "perfect" security. Sure it makes it harder, but so does obfuscated key in program's code.

Comment: That's why I said "reasonable". The user can also just write numbers on their monitor with a marker :) By server, I mean, I assume that at some point these high scores are transmitted to a server (otherwise who cares what users do if it will only ever be local?), so if the server is the record-keeper, then it's "perfect".

Comment: Like Adriano said, you can leave the data perfectly readable if you add a validation code (hash of the score + user ID): if the code does not match, the game will know that the file was tricked. It will be hard to prevent a player to overwrite his file with one copied from someone else, so it is essential that the hash includes the user ID.

Comment: @tenfour I'm also talking about "reasonable" solutions. For a simple game and a beginner programmer a key obfuscated in the implementation, or hash functions/checksums mentioned by others above are much more reasonable then your distributed solution.

Comment: If the game is local-only, then I suggest not doing any validation and just letting users do whatever they want.

Comment: @tenfour Which is not what the OP wants, obviously :)

Comment: Right, I am suggesting that it's a temptation of programmers to want to "secure" things like this, but maybe if the OP thinks about it he'll see there's actually no reason to do this. Sometimes the best solution is to do nothing at all.

Comment: You can just write data in binary mode (with some unused data padding within the file for mysteriousness). I don't understand why you guys kick in for encryption, OP just wants the file to be unreadable from a notepad...

Comment: IMHO this question does not deserve downvotes because this is a highly redundant question asked from beginner and it has a simple answer given by bames53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you just want to prevent people from easily using notepad.exe to see and edit the file content. That can be done by writing the data as binary rather than text:

```
std::ofstream out("score.dat", std::ios::binary);
std::uint32_t score = 12000;
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&score), sizeof score);
```

However it's still trivial for users to see and modify the data using a hex editor.

You could make it require a bit more work by encrypting the data first, but given that the program must have all the information necessary to read and write the file it's still pretty easy to get around.

Comment: I don't think hex editor is a issue because users need to know the file data structure to do so. Filling part of the file with unused data is probably efficient enough.

Comment: @Gall No, it's pretty easy; If they know the current value they can simply search for it. They can also save a copy of the file, then load the game and do something to change the score, and then compare the files to find the change. People use this same technique to modify memory of running executables. No need to know anything about the structure.

Comment: I agree, but we talking about experienced user then. What i wanted to say is this is not required to do over complicated security check in this case. But it is important to repeat that NOTHING is ever secured.